# Powershell PS1 clone SP permissions Exception

Tags: powershell, central-administration, content-database, stsadm

I have found this nice PS1 that clone permissions from a SPUser To Other.
When  give inputs Many things goes wrong but I have non idea what.

Has Anybody any idea about this issue?

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> $SourceUserID="i:0#.w|camp-appl\mossadm"
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> $TargetUserID="i:0#.w|camp-corp\00001969"
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> $WebAppURL="http://grispqm1:25093/"


   PS C:\Users\mossadm> C:\Users\mossadm\Desktop\CloneUser.PS1
Scanning Farm Administrators Group...
Scanning Web Application Policies...
Get-SPWebApplication : Cannot find an SPWebApplication object with Name, Id, or Url: http://sharepoint.crescent.com.
At C:\Users\mossadm\Desktop\CloneUser.PS1:109 char:13
+   $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tWebApplication:SpCmdletGetWebApplication) [Get-SPWebApp
   lication], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SpCmdletGetWebApplication

Get-SPSite : Cannot find an SPWebApplication object with Name, Id, or Url: http://sharepoint.crescent.com.
At C:\Users\mossadm\Desktop\CloneUser.PS1:138 char:21
+  $SiteCollections = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $WebAppURL -Limit All
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletGetSite:SPCmdletGetSite) [Get-SPSite], SPCmdletP
   ipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetSite

Get-SPWebApplication : Cannot find an SPWebApplication object with Name, Id, or Url: http://sharepoint.crescent.com.
At C:\Users\mossadm\Desktop\CloneUser.PS1:141 char:10
+     if( (Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL).UseClaimsAuthentication)
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tWebApplication:SpCmdletGetWebApplication) [Get-SPWebApp
   lication], SPCmdletPipeBindException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SpCmdletGetWebApplication

Permission are copied successfully!
Read : The term 'Read' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\mossadm\Desktop\CloneUser.PS1:223 char:1
+ Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/clone-sharepoint-user-permissi ...
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Read:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

> THIS IS THE SP1 SOURCE

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Function to copy user permissions
Function Copy-UserPermissions($SourceUserID, $TargetUserID, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]$Object)
{
 #Determine the given Object type and Get URL of it
    Switch($Object.GetType().FullName)
 {
  "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb"  { $ObjectType = "Site" ; $ObjectURL = $Object.URL; $web = $Object }
  "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem"
  {
   if($Object.Folder -ne $null)
   {
     $ObjectType = "Folder" ; $ObjectURL = "$($Object.Web.Url)/$($Object.Url)"; $web = $Object.Web
   }
   else
   {
    $ObjectType = "List Item"; $ObjectURL = "$($Object.Web.Url)/$($Object.Url)" ; $web = $Object.Web
   }
  }
  #Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPPictureLibrary,etc
  default { $ObjectType = "List/Library"; $ObjectURL = "$($Object.ParentWeb.Url)/$($Object.RootFolder.URL)"; $web = $Object.ParentWeb }
 }

 #Get Source and Target Users
 $SourceUser = $Web.EnsureUser($SourceUserID)
 $TargetUser = $Web.EnsureUser($TargetUserID)

 #Get Permissions of the Source user on given object - Such as: Web, List, Folder, ListItem
 $SourcePermissions = $Object.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo($SourceUser)

 #Iterate through each permission and get the details
 foreach($SourceRoleAssignment in $SourcePermissions.RoleAssignments)
 {
  #Get all permission levels assigned to User account directly or via SharePOint Group
  $SourceUserPermissions=@()
        foreach ($SourceRoleDefinition in $SourceRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
        {
   #Exclude "Limited Accesses"
   if($SourceRoleDefinition.Name -ne "Limited Access")
   {
          $SourceUserPermissions += $SourceRoleDefinition.Name
   }
        }

  #Check Source Permissions granted directly or through SharePoint Group
  if($SourceUserPermissions)
  {
   if($SourceRoleAssignment.Member -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup])  
   {
    $SourcePermissionType = "'Member of SharePoint Group - " + $SourceRoleAssignment.Member.Name +"'"

    #Add Target User to the Source User's Group
    #Get the Group
    $Group = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup]$SourceRoleAssignment.Member

    #Check if user is already member of the group - If not, Add to group
    if( ($Group.Users | where {$_.UserLogin -eq $TargetUserID}) -eq $null )
    {
      #Add User to Group
      $Group.AddUser($TargetUser)
      #Write-Host Added to Group: $Group.Name
    }    
   }
   else
   {
    $SourcePermissionType = "Direct Permission"

    #Add Each Direct permission (such as "Full Control", "Contribute") to Target User
    foreach($NewRoleDefinition in $SourceUserPermissions)
    {   
      #Role assignment is a linkage between User object and Role Definition
      $NewRoleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($TargetUser)
      $NewRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($web.RoleDefinitions[$NewRoleDefinition])

      $object.RoleAssignments.Add($NewRoleAssignment)
      $object.Update()    
    }     
   }
   $SourceUserPermissions = $SourceUserPermissions -join ";" 
   Write-Host "***$($ObjectType) Permissions Copied: $($SourceUserPermissions) at $($ObjectURL) via $($SourcePermissionType)***"
  }  
 }
}

Function Clone-SPUser($SourceUserID, $TargetUserID, $WebAppURL)
{
 ###Check Whether the Source Users is a Farm Administrator ###
 Write-host "Scanning Farm Administrators Group..."
   #Get the SharePoint Central Administration site
   $AdminWebApp = Get-SPwebapplication -includecentraladministration | where {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication}
    $AdminSite = Get-SPWeb $AdminWebApp.Url
    $AdminGroupName = $AdminSite.AssociatedOwnerGroup
    $FarmAdminGroup = $AdminSite.SiteGroups[$AdminGroupName]

 #enumerate in farm adminidtrators groups
    foreach ($user in $FarmAdminGroup.users)
    {
     if($User.LoginName.Endswith($SourceUserID,1)) #1 to Ignore Case
     {
       #Add the target user to Farm Administrator Group
    $FarmAdminGroup.AddUser($TargetUserID,"",$TargetUserID , "")
    Write-Host "***Added to Farm Administrators Group!***"
     }    
    }

 ### Check Web Application User Policies ###
 Write-host "Scanning Web Application Policies..."
  $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL  

  foreach ($Policy in $WebApp.Policies)
  {
      #Check if the search users is member of the group
     if($Policy.UserName.EndsWith($SourceUserID,1))
       {
       #Write-Host $Policy.UserName
    $PolicyRoles=@()
       foreach($Role in $Policy.PolicyRoleBindings)
       {
        $PolicyRoles+= $Role
       }
   }
  }
  #Add Each Policy found
  if($PolicyRoles)
  {
   $WebAppPolicy = $WebApp.Policies.Add($TargetUserID, $TargetUserID)
   foreach($Policy in $PolicyRoles)
   {
    $WebAppPolicy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($Policy)
   }
   $WebApp.Update()
   Write-host "***Added to Web application Policies!***"
  }

 ### Drill down to Site Collections, Webs, Lists & Libraries, Folders and List items ###
 #Get all Site collections of given web app
 $SiteCollections = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $WebAppURL -Limit All

 #Convert UserID Into Claims format - If WebApp is claims based! Domain\User to i:0#.w|Domain\User
    if( (Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL).UseClaimsAuthentication)
    {
        $SourceUserID = (New-SPClaimsPrincipal -identity $SourceUserID -identitytype 1).ToEncodedString()
  $TargetUserID = (New-SPClaimsPrincipal -identity $TargetUserID -identitytype 1).ToEncodedString()
    }

 #Loop through all site collections
    foreach($Site in $SiteCollections)
    {
  #Prepare the Target user
  $TargetUser = $Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser($TargetUserID)

     Write-host "Scanning Site Collection Administrators Group for:" $site.Url
  ###Check Whether the User is a Site Collection Administrator
     foreach($SiteCollAdmin in $Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)
        {
      if($SiteCollAdmin.LoginName.EndsWith($SourceUserID,1))
      {
          #Make the user as Site collection Admin
           $TargetUser.IsSiteAdmin = $true
           $TargetUser.Update()
       Write-host "***Added to Site Collection Admin Group***"
      }    
    }

  #Get all webs
  $WebsCollection = $Site.AllWebs
  #Loop throuh each Site (web)
  foreach($Web in $WebsCollection)
  {
       if($Web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
             {
     Write-host "Scanning Site:" $Web.Url

     #Call the function to Copy Permissions to TargetUser
     Copy-UserPermissions $SourceUserID $TargetUserID $Web   
    }

    #Check Lists with Unique Permissions
    Write-host "Scanning Lists on $($web.url)..."
    foreach($List in $web.Lists)
    {
              if($List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True -and ($List.Hidden -eq $false))
                 {
      #Call the function to Copy Permissions to TargetUser
      Copy-UserPermissions $SourceUserID $TargetUserID $List
     }

     #Check Folders with Unique Permissions
     $UniqueFolders = $List.Folders | where { $_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True }                   
                    #Get Folder permissions
                    foreach($folder in $UniqueFolders)
        {
      #Call the function to Copy Permissions to TargetUser
                                                Copy-UserPermissions $SourceUserID $TargetUserID $folder     
                    }

     #Check List Items with Unique Permissions
     $UniqueItems = $List.Items | where { $_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True }
                    #Get Item level permissions
                    foreach($item in $UniqueItems)
        {
      #Call the function to Copy Permissions to TargetUser
      Copy-UserPermissions $SourceUserID $TargetUserID $Item 
                    }
    }
  }
 }
 Write-Host "Permission are copied successfully!"

}
#Define variables for processing
$WebAppURL = "http://sharepoint.crescent.com"

#Provide input for source and Target user Ids
$SourceUser ="Crescent\TonyW"
$TargetUser ="Crescent\Salaudeen"

#Call the function to clone user access rights
Clone-SPUser $SourceUser $TargetUser $WebAppURL


Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/clone-sharepoint-user-permissions-using-powershell.html#ixzz3U0AnNwAz
```

Comment: Error says that the web application "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" could not be reached. Are you sure URL "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" exists? Is any alternate access mapping defined?

Comment: DoI understad right or should I input the Centraladmin webapp URL?

Comment: No you do not need to put centraladmin webapp url. "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" is the URL you need for cloning ? or "http://grispqm1:25093/" is the URL?

Comment: Right, grispqm1:25093/. Reading the code I thought that lines "$AdminWebApp = Get-SPwebapplication -includecentraladministration | where {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication}
    $AdminSite = Get-SPWeb $AdminWebApp.Url
    $AdminGroupName = $AdminSite.AssociatedOwnerGroup
    $FarmAdminGroup = $AdminSite.SiteGroups[$AdminGroupName]", need for the url of Centraladmin . Isn't corret?

Comment: No. URL of centraladmin is not required. as this task will be automatically done my "IncludeCentralAdministration " with filter criteria you provided. "grispqm1:25093" is the URL of central admin? or the web application on which you want to perform clone?

Comment: is the central admin url. So it just need my webapp url? Sorry but I'm completely ignorant about PShell! Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21818/discussion-between-404-and-bruno-ferreira).

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the web application you are looking for is "http://sharepoint.crescent.com". If not, update the script with correct web application URL at following line:

```
#Define variables for processing
$WebAppURL = "http://sharepoint.crescent.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to modify the variables *inside* the `.ps1` file.

Change the following lines at the bottom of your code instead of pre-declaring the variables. Here's what it's most likely supposed to be:

```
#Define variables for processing
$WebAppURL = "http://grispqm1:25093/"

#Provide input for source and Target user Ids
$SourceUser ="camp-appl\mossadm"
$TargetUser ="camp-corp\00001969"

#Call the function to clone user access rights
Clone-SPUser $SourceUser $TargetUser $WebAppURL
```

Once you change those lines to the ones I put above, save the file again and just run `C:\Users\mossadm\Desktop\CloneUser.PS1` again, without trying to declare and variables beforehand.

Also: Please remove the `Read more: http[...]` at the end of the `.ps1` file. This is automated text from when you copied the script from (most likely) http://www.sharepointdiary.com.